My side-by-side refrigerator side wall has a hole between freezer and fridge part - Why?
I bought a condo in Miami that I Airbnb, I'm rarely there but my last tenant noticed that when they put veggies into the bin they would freeze and then he sent me the following photo.

I'm not sure if this is part of the fridge or if the previous owner drilled a hole in between the freezer and fridge part.  Since I don't live in Miami, I'm having my uncle stop by to see if he can let me know the brand/model of the fridge so I can look up the details on this refrigerator.
I ended up finding this photo online, maybe this is how my refrigerator was originally set up but now the part is missing.

If the previous owner did drill a hole in between the freezer and fridge, and this isn't how the refrigerator came; what would be the best way I can close up this hole?
Thank you.

Fridges often have the model number sticker inside the fridge. You should be able to find it. then edit your question to show the manufacturer and model number. Then folks can tell you if there was something originally covering the hole or if the hole is after-market mods.

Yeah, I’ll get that information and post an update.

Since you now know there's an adjustable damper that's supposed to cover the hole, you should be able to hit up one of the appliance parts stores using the make and model number to find a replacement.

This is the model # of the fridge: https://www.partswarehouse.com/Frigidaire-DFHS2313MFJA-Side-By-Side-Refrigerator-s/497047.htm . From looking at the manuals, I'm not seeing that hole showing; so maybe previous owner made the hole.

A typical side-by-side refrigerator has only one cooling system (compressor, etc.) and uses that to cool both the refrigerator and freezer compartments. There are typically a number of physical and/or electronic controls to adjust the temperature of each compartment.
This particular hole is one of those controls, and the adjustment is done using the missing rotating pieces that open/close the hole to varying degrees.
Typical residential refrigerator/freezer design (side-by-side and other form factors) is a series of compromises to:

Keep parts cost low - hence only one of each active component whenever possible
Keep design simple - hence designed to only run properly in a narrow ambient temperature range (e.g., I found a manual for one that says min/max 55F - 110F with recommended 60F - 90F), which also helps to...
Keep energy costs low

So while some refrigerator/freezer will have two separate specific temperature settings (e.g., set freezer for 0F and refrigerator for 38F), far more common is some ambiguous relative numbers (1 to 5 or 1 to 10 or similar) for each compartment, which adjust a thermostat in one compartment and the relative temperature of the two compartments. This hole - and the missing pieces - is a part of the entire system.

Ty for the detailed reply, I did not know this about side by side fridges but from looking at the manual based on the model # it doesn't seem like the hole in my first photo was existing from the manufacturer. https://www.partswarehouse.com/Frigidaire-DFHS2313MFJA-Side-By-Side-Refrigerator-s/497047.htm

Fridges with freezers use cold air from the freezer section to cool the fridge section though an adjustable vent(shown in the second picture).
The passage hole/duct surface seems to be damaged, a section broken off the side.
Unknown if a new vent/air control would cover/stay on or if some work(epoxy glue) needed to repair the hole.

Yeah, looking at the model # of the fridge; I don't believe this one had an existing hold from the manufacturer.  https://www.partswarehouse.com/Frigidaire-DFHS2313MFJA-Side-By-Side-Refrigerator-s/497047.htm
